# How to add 'Pin to Startbar' or 'Pin to Taskbar' for all users or default user

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

In windows XP, you can add a shortcut to the start menu or desktop for all users by copying/moving the shortcut to

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users[Desktop|Start Menu]

I know same is the case in Windows 7 with a slightly different path (C:\Users\Public). However I'm still trying to find out how to add a 'shortcut' for all users. There is no C:\Users\Public\Taskbar.

Any ideas? Or is it just not available as a feature?

Comment: You could use a login script to pin things.

Comment: Any specific examples that you might have? Would they be VB scripts or regular BATCH files? Just wondering.

Answer (score 16):

Items pinned for the current user are located here: "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar"

There's no Public/All Users AppData anymore, so I don't think there's anyplace you can put it for 'all users' that already exist.

It *does* appear that you can add them to the Default user's profile, which would at least add them for any user profiles created after the pin entries are made("C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar").

HTH

Comment: +1, just to clarify though there's no location to add pinned items for *all users*, but it can be added to the default profile so new user *start off* with them.

Comment: Path still relevant in Windows 10, and even Windows Server 2016 as well. ;)

Comment: This does not appear to work in Windows Server 2019 =(

Answer (score -1):

I still haven't found a way to change the default taskbar programs for all users but you can add and delete items from all users default start menu by navigating to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\ you can change items on here like in Windows XP.

Comment: -1 OP is asking about the taskbar, not the Start Menu or Desktop. This is not a forum, this is a question and _answers_ site. No answer, no post.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the taskbar folder from `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned` to `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\`. After you have done that, open the taskbar folder and delete any shortcuts you don't want.

Comment: This would only cause those shortcuts to be added to the taskbar of *users who have never logged in before*.  Existing users won't get changed.

Comment: -1 Different way of wording [Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's](http://superuser.com/users/23133) [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/120281/120290#120290)